# flutter build issue when use fluttertoast in pubspec.yaml

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

> geting error when use fluttertoast in pubspec.yaml file get error on build.

- kotlin-gradle-plugin : '1.3.50'
- com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5
- com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2
- https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip

[image: fluttertoast error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 30 in your `app/build.gradle`

```
...
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    ...

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        ...
    }
}
...
```

If nothing happened try to roll back to gradle 3.5.0. Inside `build.gradle`:

```
...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }
...
```